# Glyphfriend not displaying icons

Tags: visual-studio-2017

So, VS Community 2017 offer me to download Glyphfriend.
I installed it, but it's not displaying the icons.

I'm importing all the libraries as usual, like this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/Site.css"));
```

I tried also importing all the libraries above directly in the page, but didn't solve the problem.

I'm doing this to display the icons

```
<ul class="icons-list">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="fa-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            //Tried using span as well
            <li><a href="#"><span class="mdi-sync"></span> Update data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="octicon-list-unordered"></i> Detailed log</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon-check"></i> Statistics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cross"></i> Clear list</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

None of then worked. It works only If I don't use GlyphFriend

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span>
```

Any ideas?